# Why and how on earth would referencing a variable in the console.log fix a loading bug I've had?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

This is hard for me to fathom, and i don't like the 'solution' as it really shouldn't solve my problem.

I have a function that 40% of the time does not follow entirely though. At first I thought it was due to me manipulating img and iframe elements on the fly, however i have done various things to make sure cache and loading is sorted before they do their thing.

In particular, a thing i was doing with the `newCover` variable executed itself only 60% of the time. In my frustration I console logged `newCover` right at the end of the function, to try understand why it just didn't appear sometimes.

But bizarrely, because i'm console logging the variable, i get 100% success rate with the function doing what it should.

Why is that?!

You can see it working on the third post here: http://syndex.me

Here is the code:

```
albumCover = function(){
$(".forPhotoset").each(function () {
    var forPhotoset = $(this);
    var myFrame = forPhotoset.find("iframe");
    myFrame.hide();
    myFrame.load(function(){
        var newCover = myFrame.contents().find('.photoset').children(':first-child').children(':first-child');
        newCover.children(':first-child').remove();
        var psPre = newCover.attr("href")+ '?' + (Math.random() * 1);
        newCover.append("<img src='"+ psPre +"' alt='Cover Page' />");
        var psHeight = newCover.find('img');
        psHeight.load(function(){
            if (psHeight.height()>heightRef){
                psHeight.height(heightRef);
            }
        })
        newCover.detach();
        forPhotoset.append(newCover); //only executes 60% of the time
        console.log(newCover);//i added this, now i get 100% success rate?!
    })
});
}
```

Comment: Actually I'll add my own theory. There's a lot going on when the page loads, in terms of DOMs, jQuery etc. Maybe referencing the variable twice is forcing the script to take more note of that variable? But that seems like such a hack.

Comment: Are you saying everything in the `.load()` callback executes 60% of the time, or only the line `forPhotoset.append(newCover);?

Comment: Try using `newCover.appendTo(forPhotoset)` instead of  `newCover.detach(); forPhotoset.append(newCover);`

Comment: Try console.log("Any old text") and also try replacing it with sleep().  If it works, we'll know it's not the variable being accessed that "fixes" the problem.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. Like Steve Wellens suggests, It seems it's the delay introduced by a print statement that makes the difference and not the variable being accessed. Javascript doesn't have a native sleep() function though.

Comment: does it work 60% or 100% of the time if you have the console open, but no console.log?

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of a guess but it could be that the console.log call is slowing the timing of the script slightly and allowing other dom changes more time to complete. Maybe try wrapping your call in a setTimeout() to see if that has the same effect as the console.log call.